# Linux x64 Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I am in the process of creating my own toy programming language called SP4RX following Jack Crenshaw's amazing compiler tutorials (translated into c++). I am building on a 64 bit Ubuntu system, and am thus learning assembly for the compiler. I am making an addition program as a start: but I get a segmentation fault and the core is dumped :(

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
mov rax, 0
add rax, [num1B]
add rax, [num2B]
mov [result], rax
mov rdx, [result]
mov rcx, 8  
mov rax, 4
mov rbx, 1
int 80h

mov rbx, 1
mov rax, 0
int 80h


section .data

    num1B: db 0Ah
num2B: db 0Ah
result: db 0

section .bss
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program does not add two bytes, but two quadwords, as you are using 64-bit registers for load/store. One of them is being read from a misaligned address, hence, the segfault.

`num1B`, `num2B` and `result` should be defined as `dq`, not `db`.

```
section .data

num1B:  dq 0Ah
num2B:  dq 0Ah
result: dq 00h
```

If you still want to add two bytes and store the result in another byte, use 8-bit registers, or use `movzx/movsx` instructions to zero/sign extend the content of a byte to a full 64-bit register.

```
_start:  ;8-bit register version
mov al, 0
add al, [num1B]
add al, [num2B]
mov [result], al
movzx rdx,byte ptr [result]

_start:  ;MOVZX version
movzx rax,byte [num1B]
movzx rbx,byte ptr [num2B]
add rax,rbx
mov [result],al
movzx rdx,[result]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Intel guidelines](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/data-alignment-when-migrating-to-64-bit-intel-architecture) for data alignment on 64-bit Intel architectures,

> Under the 16-bit Intel architecture, data alignment had little effect on performance, and its use was entirely optional. Under IA-32, aligning data correctly can be an important optimization, although its use is still optional with a very few exceptions, where correct alignment is mandatory. The 64-bit environment, however, imposes more-stringent requirements on data items. Misaligned objects cause program exceptions.

I'm not certain if this issue applies here but it looks to me like `num1B, num2B,` and `result` are allocated single bytes, while `mov`'s to the 64-bit registers used in the code will try to do fetches of multiple unaligned bytes.  If the issue isn't alignment, it might be one of reading past the end of the `.data` section.